# Second Order Transfer Function : Imaginary component in $R$?

Tags: transfer-function

I have been looking at the following transfer function:

$$ H(z) = \tfrac12 -  \tfrac12 z^{-2} $$

Given the usual method for finding $\theta$ and $R$ in the complex plane, I calculate that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $R = j\sqrt{\frac12}$

This would initially make me think that the conjugate zero pair here is 90° from the real axis, however this imaginary $R$ component has thrown me completely - the equivalent frequency response also seems odd to me as it shows zero at DC and Nyquist with a gentle curve upwards in between.

What is going on here? I think that $R$ in the complex plane can't be imaginary, but don't understand how to arrive at the correct angle and magnitude for the conjugate poles.

Comment: Without showing us how you arrived at these values (and maybe explaining what you actually mean by 'theta' and 'R') we can't say where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

If you're looking for the zeros of $H(z)$, try $z_0=1$ or $z_0=-1$. If that works, try to figure out why, and derive it yourself. Then, think about what the magnitude and the phase of those zeros might be.

---

EDIT (in reaction to your comment): If you have a second-order polynomial with real-valued coefficients, then two complex conjugated zeros are not the only option; you can also have two real-valued zeros.

Comment: So I was originally assuming a solution of the form: $H(z) = (1-Zz^{-1} )(1-Z^* z^{-1})$; where $Z$/$Z^*$ is a pair of complex conjugate zeros $Z = Re^{j\theta}$, whereas if I assume the following form: $H(z) = (1-Zz^{-1} )(1+Z^* z^{-1} )$; It returns: $H(z) = 1-2Rjsin(\theta)z^{-1}-R^2z^{-1}$; which gives me two real zeros at -1 and +1?

(Doing this without direct inspection of the transfer function)

Comment: can you show the steps between the last and next-to-last equations, Eddy?

Comment: Made a mistake, should be $H(z) = 1+2Rz^{-1}jsin(\theta)-R^2z^{-2}$. Found like so: $H(z) = (1-Zz^{-1})(1+Z^*z^{-1}) = 1-Zz^{-1}+Z^*z^{-1}-ZZ^*z^{-2}$. Then substituting $Z = Re^{-j\theta}, Z^* = Re^{j\theta}$, $H(z) = 1-Re^{-j\theta}z^{-1}+Re^{j\theta}z^{-1}-R^2z^{-2}$.With final result from sub. $e^{-j\theta}$ & $e^{j\theta}$ with $cos(\theta)-jsin(\theta)$ and $cos(\theta)+jsin(\theta)$. So in this case the zeros are real, but then in the case where theta is not pi / zero, such as in the following transfer function: H(z) = 1+z^{-1}-z^{-2}. I am unsure how to proceed with 2Rjsin(\theta)

Comment: My thought at the moment is that $jsin(\theta)$ is a 90 degree phase shift, so the answer involves that concept

Answer (score 1):

The **polar** representation of a nonzero complex number in the form

$$ z = R e^{j \theta} $$ requires that $R > 0$ ; a positive real number. Setting $R = j\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} $ violates this.

Your transfer function is

$$ H(z) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} z^{-2} $$

and you want to find its zeros.

Let's find the zeros of the following transfer function instead :

$$ G(z) = 1 - z^{-2} $$

it's very easy to see ( from $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ ) that

$$ G(z) = 1 - z^{-2} = (1 - z^{-1})( 1 +  z^{-1}) $$

Then the **zeros** of $G(z)$ are :

$$ G(z) = 0 \implies z = \{ -1 , 1 \} $$

from which you would argue that

$$ z = 1 \implies R = 1 ~~,~~ \theta = 0 $$
and
$$ z = -1 \implies R = 1 ~~,~~ \theta = \pi $$

And the zeros of $H(z)$ will be the same, since $H(z) = \frac{1}{2} G(z)$.